# Passing a Vector made of a Class to a function (C++)

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm running into a lot of problems with this, primarily being that my passed Vector of my Class keeps getting flagged as an undeclared identifier. Any help on solving the problem or explanations to help me figure out what I don't understand would be greatly appreciated.

So here is a simplified version of what I have now:

main.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "vehicle.h"

int main()
{
   int menuSelection;

   vector<Vehicle> inventory;

   do
   {
        cout << "Please make a selection:" << endl << endl;
        cout << "1:   Display Inventory" << endl;
                     .......
        cout << "8 : Write inventory to file and exit" << endl << endl;

        if (menuSelection == 1)
        {
            if (inventory.empty())
                cout << "Database empty" << endl;
            else
                display(inventory);
                     .......
    } while (menuSelection != 8);

    return 0;
}
```

vehicle.h

```
#pragma once
#include "functions.h"

class Vehicle
{
   private:
         string VIN;
         int year;
                    .......
//   public:
//        string getVIN();
                    .......
}
```

functions.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void display(vector<Vehicle>);
                    .......

void display(vector<Vehicle>& in)
{
        Vehicle v;
        cout << "VIN: " << v.getVIN(in)
}
                    .......
```

I've tried a bunch of different things to get it to work so that's why a lot of stuff may seem like odd syntax (I'm also not very good). My assignment is to have a menu in main.cpp which will create a vector from a class stored in vehicle.h, and then the menu is supposed to call functions which are located in functions.h that will communicate through vehicle.h to a fourth not included vehicle.cpp to work with information from the class.

Comment: Your first problem is `vector<MyClass>` is undefined because `MyClass` is not in the code.  But since it's not all there I really can't tell.  Start smaller.  Create the vehicle class all by itself.  Test it and get it working.  Then move on to integrating into the menu and functions.  Your first main will only create your vehicle object and prove it works.  Then add your functions.  Finally add the vector functionality.

Comment: MyClass was a typo, it should be Vehicle. I can get the Vehicle class to compile just fine on its own. However as soon as I add main.cpp all of the members (VIN, year) in the class return with "unknown override specifier". I don't know how to proceed, I'm assuming it's an error in how I've made my vector.

Comment: compiling just fine and working just fine are too different things.  It's compiling but not working.  Forget the vector.  Get the class working for a single instance and move from there.  A vector is just a container of things.

Answer (score 1):

In `functions.h`, `void display(vector<Vehicle>);` does not compile because `Vehicle` is undeclared at this point.

Also, in `functions.h`, `void display(vector<Vehicle>& in)` is a different overload to the previous prototype (the `&` makes a difference), probably not what you intended. And then you place a function body in `functions.h` -- this should not be there.

You need to organize your code so that `Vehicle` class definition appears, and then `functions.h` includes that.

---

So `vehicle.h` should look like:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
// do NOT include functions.h

class Vehicle
{
  // ...
};
```

and then `functions.h` should look like:

```
#pragma once
#include "vehicle.h"
// do NOT do "using namespace std;" in a header and don't include any unnecessary headers

void display(vector<Vehicle> &in);
```

and then `functions.cpp` should `#include "functions.h"` and contain the function body for `display`.

Answer (score 0):

`undeclared identifier` means the compiler sees a name but don't see a declaration of that name (as a variable, class, function, etc.). It happens in your code in a few places, for example:

- `MyClass` is used but not declared (main.cpp)
- `Vehicle` is used but not declared (functions.h)
- You use `Vehicle.v` but `v` not declared in class `Vehicle` (in addition, I doubt that this is what you intended - if you use class name `Vehicle.v` it means accessing a static variable, as opposed to `vehicle.v`).

It seems you lack some basic background. The most important thing is that you learn to decipher compiler errors, so at least you understand what went wrong.

Comment: MyClass was an accident, in my actual code it's Vehicle. As far as Vehicle in functions.h, I have it used in my prototypes because I'm trying to pass my vector that I've made with the class. With Vehicle v I'm attempting to create a class object so that I may later access object members.